# Where to download ASTER scene boundaries?

Tags: remote-sensing, download, aster

I am looking for a shapefile of [ASTER](http://asterweb.jpl.nasa.gov/) scene boundaries for the Kansas and Oklahoma region.  The attached screenshot from [GLOVIS](http://glovis.usgs.gov/) is what I'm after, except I need polygon footprints with relevant attributes such as scene ID and year.  Is such a product available for download?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASTER scenes are not captured in a regular, repeating grid like the path/row system of Landsat. Instead, they are more scattered due to the much narrower swath (only 60 km versus 180 km for Landsat), off-nadir capture, and imagery tasking. You can see the scene boundaries in GLOVIS:

[image: ASTER on GLOVIS]

The [listing of ASTER repositories](http://asterweb.jpl.nasa.gov/data.asp) has a number of other locations where you can search for scenes. I've used [NASA REVERB](http://reverb.echo.nasa.gov/reverb/) since it's the only repository (as of a few years ago) that offered level 2 data to NASA-approved users. If you really want to have an offline directory of all ASTER scenes, you would probably have to crawl through the [ASTER data pool at LPDAAC](http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/ASTT/) and create geometries in a shapefile/geodatabase based on the bounding box coordinates in the XML metadata files:

[image: XML bounding box]

Comment: Is ASTER data is downloadable till date?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of the possibility to download a polygon Shapefile of the footprint of the ASTER image, but it may exist. One alternative would be to use [`gdaltindex`](http://www.gdal.org/gdaltindex.html) to create a Shapefile assigning the filename (and potentially metadata stored in the filename) as an attribute.